# Extract duplicate records from CSV based on selected headings

Tags: php, ruby, arrays, algorithm, csv

I have a CSV file with several thousand customer's details. I would like to extract duplicated customers based on having the same values for selected headers.

For example, I would like to extract all customers where there exists more than one record with the same 'surname' and 'postcode'.

```
"surname","postcode","other-stuff-that-doesn't-matter"...
"smith",  "AB1 2CD", "dxfh"...
"smith",  "AB1 2CD", "98sf"...
"jones",  "BC2 3DE", "as0j"...
"jones",  "BC2 3DE", "9as6"...
"blogs",  "BC2 3DE", "9as6"...
```

Based on the above, the program would return a new CSV like so:

```
"surname","postcode","other-stuff-that-doesn't-matter"...
"smith",  "AB1 2CD", "dxfh"...
"smith",  "AB1 2CD", "98sf"...
"jones",  "BC2 3DE", "as0j"...
"jones",  "BC2 3DE", "9as6"...
```

### EDIT

Thanks for the help so far. I think I have a working solution, but I'm interested to know if this can be optimised (I'm sure it can!).

```
set_one    = Set.new
set_two    = Set.new
duplicates = Array.new
headers    = nil

CSV.foreach('customers.csv', :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
  headers = row.headers unless headers
  values = [row[:surname], row[:post_code]]
  if set_one.include? values
    set_two << values
  else
    set_one << values 
  end
end

CSV.foreach('customers.csv', :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
  values = [row[:surname], row[:post_code]]
  if set_two.include? values
    duplicates << row
  end
end

CSV.open("duplicate-customers.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << headers
  duplicates.each { |dupe| csv << dupe }
end
```

Comment: Put it into a database like mysql or sqlite, then run an SQL query. Is probably most flexible.

Comment: @hakre Thanks, I'll likely run the script irregularly, with new CSV files and with different input values, so it doesn't seem sensible to create a database each time.

Comment: Well some kind of database you might need to create anyway. Either based on the actual CSV file on disk (disk based database), or within an Array in memory (in-memory based database). Importing the CSV into a temporary (maybe in memory) sqlite database doesn't sound that bad to me actually.

Comment: @hakre You're right, I was probably finding an excuse not to any SQL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's read in the csv first (doesn't handle escapes or quotes, just an example)

```
csv = []
columns = []
File.read('csv.file') do |row|
  if csv.empty?
    columns=row.split(',')
  else
    row_data={}
    row.split(',').each_with_index do |c,i|
      row_data[columns[i]] = c
    end
    csv << row_data
  end
end
```

Ok, what do we do with the data? It looks like:

```
[{'surname' => 'smith', 'postcode' => '1234', 'otherstuff' => 'xyz' },
 {'surname' => 'jones', 'postcode' => '1234', 'otherstuff' => 'xyz' },
 {'surname' => 'smith', 'postcode' => '2345', 'otherstuff' => 'xyz' },
 {'surname' => 'smith', 'postcode' => '1234', 'otherstuff' => 'xyz' }]
```

How about something like:

```
csv.select do |c| 
  csv.any? do |s| 
    s['surname'].eql?(c['surname']) && s['postcode'].eql?(c['postcode']) 
  end
end
```

Ok that's slow and not clever. Let's proceed to solution 2, generate a hash key from the data we want to check for uniqueness:

```
sneakyhash={}
csv.each do |row|
  magic_string = [row['surname'], row['postcode']].join("--MaGiCaL--SpLiTTinG--StRiNG--")
  if sneakyhash[magic_string].nil?
    sneakyhash[magic_string] = 1
  else
    puts "this guy looks suspicious: " + row.join(,)
  end
end
```

Far from optimal, but just thinking out loud here. If it's a "one time only" kind of thing and you just need to parse a file, go with what you can come up with.

What you probably want to do is store this identifying string in an array or hash while reading the csv in and see if current row matches any of the stored unique rows and do something if it does.

Comment: Thanks, that made me laugh! You got me on the right track. I need to keep a reference to the whole row though, including the other columns (that don't need to be duplicates) so I can then include each record (including the first) the in duplicates csv. See my edit for where I am now.